# Unable to launch the IIS express web server port 80 is in use

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have two Solutions in visual studio 2015: **CDN** and a **website**.

CDN *applicartionhost.config* are in `C:\xxxx\CCC\CCC\Dev\CCC\.vs\config`

Site Config:

```
            <site name="CCC.Web" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\XXXX\CCC\CCC\Dev\CCC\CCC.Web" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:www.trueq.com.co" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Website applicartionhost.config are in `C:\xxxx\YYY\YYY\Dev\YYY\.vs\config`

Site Config:

```
 <site name="YYY" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\XXXX\YYY\YYY\Dev\YYY\YYY" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:tq.pastatic.com" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

When I run one solution it runs fine, but when I try to run the other it shows an error: Unable to launch the iis express web server port 80 is in use.

I don't know what to do.

I tried uninstall and reinstall IIS 10, delete both applicartionhost.config, change ports, nothing works.

Comment: did you check already if any other process has taken already that port? netstat -n -b perhaps

Comment: just a shot into the blue: Is Skype running on this machine? Skype sometimes blocks port 80 I think.

Comment: Yes, already check Skype port.

Comment: and process system (id:4) is taking port 80

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two processes listening at the same TCP port.

When you two solutions, you have two instances of IIS express running.

In (the real) IIS, you can use the hostname to switch to different sites, because it is only one process listening.